# Declaring button control in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am trying to declare a button named "viewButton" with a image as the background of the button. How can i go about doing it can anyone help me with it?
Below is the code i tired but is not a correct one.

Code:
viewButton.Background = "/AlarmClock;component/Images/page_preview.png";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<Button>
    <Button.Background>
        <ImageBrush Source="/AlarmClock;component/Images/page_preview.png" />
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

just make sure the file is maked as "Resource" in visual studio. Alternatively you can mark it as "Content" and use it like this:

```
        <ImageBrush Source="/Images/page_preview.png" />
```

I don't know if you need to assign the background programatically (because you can do it in markup), but if you do here is what you need to say:

```
viewButton.Background = new ImageBrush
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("", UriKind.Relative))
}
```

[FURTHER]

in order set margin programmatically:

```
viewButton.Margin = new Thickness(left, top, right, bottom);
```

Comment: how about setting the margin programatically??